# Is every pad in eagle a via?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

Correct me if Im wrong, a via is a hole that join two or more layers in a PCB. 
I have a PCB design who has the pads to solder but I want solder only one side, do all my pads that are connected to my top and bottom layer are plated through holes? are they automatic connected together? this picture is for example a capacitor who has both layers connected, is a pad, do I have to solder both sides?  [image]

Comment: As a side note, you should make sure your DRC settings are correct, and also where possible try to use thicker traces. The width of those traces seem pointlessly narrow and the clearance on the right hand pad of the capacitor is questionable.

Comment: Thank you, I used the Design Rules from Osh Park to do the traces

Comment: Even still, just because that is the smallest they can do, doesn't necessarily mean you should go that small - narrower traces = higher resistance. On power lines for example (which based on the proximity to the crystal I'm guessing the left hand side of C1 is GND) can lead to more noise and higher losses.

Comment: I second Tom Carpenter.  The design rules represent _the absolute smallest that OSHPark can reliably manufacture_.  Unless you have a compelling reason, you should keep the traces much thicker.  For an average layout, if I have the space, I'll usually use 12 mil for logic and something bigger for power.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In normal two-sided PCB production, all holes, whether vias or holes for component pins, will be plated to connect both sides of the board, unless specifically declared non-plated, and a separate drill file provided to the board maker..

Of course, if you are making the board yourself using normal home etching techniques, no holes will be plated, and you will have to solder wires in holes where you want connections between the top and bottom layers.

If the board shown in your question is home-made, then you will have to solder both sides to ensure proper connections.  If the board is commercially-made, the holes should be plated, so you will only need to solder the pins on the bottom side.

Comment: Im looking at oshpark and they said Plated slots aren’t supported. Are slots the same as vias or pads?

Comment: Holes in vias or pads are normally drilled, so they are round (square or rectangular drills can only be made form unobtainium :-) ).  A slot would have to be milled, which is a separate machining procedure.  A slot would be an oval or elongated hole.

Comment: Ooh! then I hope OshPark support Plated holes! thank you very much!

Comment: It would be very strange if OSH Park or any other board shop did not do plated holes, as that is a normal requirement for almost any PC board.